# Retrieve multiple rows from an ODBC source with a UNION query

Tags: sql, sql-server, c, winapi, listview

I am retrieving multiple rows into a listview control from an ODBC source.  For simple SELECTs it seems to work well with a statement attribute of SQL_SCROLLABLE.  How do I do this with a UNION query (with two selects)?

The most likely server will be MS SQL Server (probably 2005).  The code is C for the Win32 API.

This code sets (what I think is) a server side cursor which feeds data into the ODBC driver that roughly corresponds with the positional fetches of SQLFetchScroll, which is turn feeds the cache for the listview. (Sometimes using SQL_FETCH_FIRST or SQL_FETCH_LAST as well as):

```
SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt1Fetch,
               SQL_ATTR_CURSOR_SCROLLABLE,
               (SQLPOINTER)SQL_SCROLLABLE,
               SQL_IS_INTEGER);
SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt1Fetch,
               SQL_ATTR_CURSOR_SENSITIVITY,
               (SQLPOINTER)SQL_INSENSITIVE,
               SQL_IS_INTEGER);
...
retcode = SQLGetStmtAttr(hstmt1Fetch,
                         SQL_ATTR_ROW_NUMBER,
                         &CurrentRowNumber,
                         SQL_IS_UINTEGER,
                         NULL);
...
retcode = SQLFetchScroll(hstmt1Fetch, SQL_FETCH_ABSOLUTE, Position);
```

(The above is is a fragment from working code for a single SELECT).

Is this the best way to do it?  Given that I need to retrieve the last row to get the number of rows and populate the end buffer is there a better way of doing it?  (Can I use forward only scrolling?)

Assuming yes to the above, how do I achieve the same result with a UNION query?

LATE EDIT: The problem with the union query being that effectively it forces forward only scrolling which breaks SQLFetchScroll(hstmt1Fetch, SQL_FETCH_ABSOLUTE, Position).  The answer is I suspect: "you can't".  And it really means redesigning the DB to included either a view or a single table to replace the UNION.  But I'll leave the question open in case I have missed something.

Answer (score 1):

can you not define a view on the db server that does the union query for you, so from the client code it just looks like a single select?

if you can't, can you just issue the union operation as part of your select, e.g.

```
select some_fields from table1
union
select same_fields from table2
```

and treat the result as a single result set?

Comment: I was trying to avoid views because it would require a database update (And not all servers support them).  If I was to so a db update, I may just require the DB to support a single table.

Comment: and forward only scrolling would probably be more efficient if that is an option

Comment: I am allready doing that.  Fetch positioning is not allowed on SQL forward only scrolling (at leasting SQL Server), which is the root cause of my problem.

Comment: [@David L Morris] but if all you're doing is filling a list, why do you need fetch positioning?

Comment: The list might be a million items long.  Inly the items in view or near to being in view or at the very end of the list are cached locally.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is just needing to get the last row to get the number of rows and caching the last few rows (I assume if there are a million items in the select that you're not populating a drop-list with all of them) then you may be able to take advantage of the `ROW_NUMBER()` function of SQL Server 2005

You could:

```
select count(*) 
from (select blah UNION select blah)
```

to get the number of rows.

Then:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() as rownum,blah 
from (select blah UNION select blah) 
where rownum between minrow and maxrow
```

to just fetch the rows that you need to display/cache

But seriously folks, if you're selecting items from a million-row table, you might want to consider a different mechanism

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `union` to make a derived table ?

```
select * from 
(select field1, field from table1
union all
slect field1, filed2 from table2) a
```

Comment: Yes.  That was the question.  Select works Union of two selects does not.